# Collision 2D - Detecting the side

Tags: c, 2d, sdl, sprite, graphic

I'm working on my brick breaker and to make a proper colliding system so as to make the ball switch direction logically, I have to detect with which side of the brick the ball collided.
Here is my current script :

```
int sprite_collide(const Sprite item1, const Sprite item2)
{
    if(item1.sShow == 0 || item2.sShow == 0) // return if any item is invisible
        return 0;

    if(item1.sCollide == 0 || item2.sCollide == 0) 
        return 0;

    if((item2.sPos.x >= item1.sPos.x + item1.sImg->w)      // too right
    || (item2.sPos.x + item2.sImg->w <= item1.sPos.x) // too left
    || (item2.sPos.y >= item1.sPos.y + item1.sImg->h) // too up
    || (item2.sPos.y + item2.sImg->h <= item1.sPos.y))  // too down
    return 0;

return 1;
}
```

The Sprite Struct :

```
typedef struct Sprite
{
    SDL_Surface *sImg;
    SDL_Rect sPos;

    int sShow; // If sShow = 1, we show it.
    int sCollide; // If sCollide = 1, then it's physic.
    int sMoving; // If sMoving = 1, it'll be able to move
    float sSpeed;

    int sLife;
    int sInit;

} Sprite;
```

Comment: and what is the behavior you get by running this code?

Comment: chouaib : If one of these item don't have the collider, or if one of these item arn't shown, we don't treat them (i have some item that doesn't have a collider).

If the item 2 is far too right, left, top or bottom, then it's not colliding.

If we reached all these "ifs", that mean there's a collision.

Comment: are your sprites rectangles? could you paste your sprite struct code?

Comment: Yes, everything is rectangle, it's not going to be a complicated one

Comment: you mentionned in the comment bellow that you return `COLHAUT` `COLBAS` etc ... can you post that part of code.
P.S: still don't understand your question

Comment: I meant to say that, i tried something i deleted that would return COLHAUT, COLBAS, COLGAUCHE or COLDROITE. Currently my function only return 0 for no collision and 1 for a collision. It have to return 5 differents value into knowing the side it collides, and i have no idea how to detect the side.

Answer (score 1):

You are just looking for any collision and then you return an int value. I would suggest to make another method to identify which side of the brick the ball touched.
Something like this:

```
int sprite_collide(const Sprite item1, const Sprite item2)
{
    if(item2.sPos.x >= item1.sPos.x + item1.sImg->w) // trop à droite
        doAction(1);
    if(item2.sPos.x + item2.sImg->w <= item1.sPos.x) // trop à gauche
        doAction(2);
    ...
}
```

And then the `doAction()` method will do something when the brick touches the side like you mentioned in the comments.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually my method return either COLHAUT, COLBAS, COLDROITE or COLGAUCHE when it touches the TOP, the BOTTOM, the RIGHT and the lEFT. Yet i've tried to figure out yesterday how to know which side the ball collided.

My best idea is the get from the middle of the brick, deduce the side (it's either left or right, top or bottom) but the problem is that it can be Top Right. In this case i still don't know where the ball is, except it's either Top, or Right. But i feel like this is going way too far, and an easiest solution is possible.

Thanks for responding !

Comment: If it's top right then the collision is indeed just at the top. You have to do some math to make the ball bounce back from the location it has touched the top. I think you can't just get the output back like 'The ball touched Top Right', since it could also touch the top  between the top middle and top right.

Comment: By "Top Right" it means that the code would have touched either the top side or the right side, not the corner, since it would detect it the ball is top or bottom from the middle, and right or left. It can be 4 combos here.